# Android action bar's title color not changing

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionmode

I would like to change the contextual action bar's title text color and back button colour.

Please find the code i am using, still i couldn't able to achieve

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/dark_blue_Shade1</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Please help me to fix

Comment: are you calling this theme in your manifest?

Comment: your manifest please

Comment: @TomerShemesh i am calling this theme

Comment: @Suresh your question was my answer , your code works for me :) +1

Answer (score 2):

```
</style>
        <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>

        </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">#0061C2</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item><!--hiding the icon ..in case you want it..-->
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

and in the manifest ...you can apply this theme for your app

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" ><!--this is that theme-->
```

or just to one of your activities

```
<activity
            android:name="eddine.charef.mechalikh.swipedemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/mainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" 
          >
```

that's all

**Edit:** i found this in android developpers website

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

here is the link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: if u notice my code we have used parent        "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar", because of this style is not applying?

Comment: I used your code and getting the title text color as expected but when i change the parent of my theme style is not applying.

Comment: Its not working with appcompat
i.e <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> its not working for this theme